# Save editing html file to specific folder

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, tinymce-4

I have build a project that user can upload,view,edit and save their file in the specific folder. I using TinyMCE for the editing but I can't find the way how to save the content after editing. Anybody can give some advice to me?

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can save values of your TinyMCE control.

```
String OutPath = Server.MapPath("~/myfiles/test.txt");  // here '~/' refers to root of your website

            StreamWriter Out1 = new StreamWriter(OutPath);
            Out1.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            Out1.Close(); //Close File
```

Comment: how about using save plugins in tinymce?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you need to save the html in the `HtmlFiles` folder inside your root folder and the file name is `test.html`.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/HtmlFiles/test.html");
File.WriteAllText(path ,yorTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: where to use this code?in button block statement?do you know how to use this statement in javascript?

Comment: i not sure yorTextBox.Text is replace to tinymce or textarea.Text?

Comment: @Syafiq when you ask question please ask with what you have tried so far and code currently you have. then we don't want to guess

Comment: function btnsave_onclick() {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/WordExcelPPointToHtm/test.html");
            File.WriteAllText(path, editor.Text );
         }

Comment: this is look like javascript code, you need to place this code inside c# code behind click event of asp.net button

Comment: i have try it,normally before this I using the database to store the file..but in this situation it is new for me because want to save in folder..

Comment: I not use asp button..but i use input type=button..it can't call in code behind..do you have any suggestion to make this on javascript?